# In Liferay what is the "kernel" package?

Tags: liferay, java-package

I am writing a Liferay hook.

When referencing a Java class in Liferay, the "Organize imports" dialog in Eclipse often offers me either `com.liferay.portal.TheClass` or `com.liferay.portal.kernel.TheClass`.

On which criteria should I choose one or the other?
Is there a general rule?
What is the philosophy behind this [kernel](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/index.html?com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/package-summary.html) package?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, kernel package is in the portal-service.jar, which is globally visible to portlets, if you have two implementations, my bet would be always the "kernel" version as there's a good chance that the other one is located within portal-impl.jar which sits in Liferay's WEB-INF/lib folder hence it's not visible to other applicaitons like portlets, hooks, etc.

Comment: So portlet implementors should almost always use the `kernel` one, right?

Comment: *always*? I wouldn't go that far and state this. However, if you can choose between a class from portal-service.jar and one from portal-impl.jar: portal-service is the one you can reach from plugins.

Comment: As someone wise says: "It depends" :) but honestly, if there are let's say 2 implementations, from a plugin (portlet/hook/ext) the kernel package is accessible while the portal package is not (except through PortalClassInvoker), so if the two implemenations are for the similar job, it's easier(perhaps better choice) to use the kernel version. Do you agree Olaf?